# Storing arabic into mysql generate error

Tags: php, mysql, arabic

Question: How can I store Text written in Arabic into MySQL table?

Current situation: I always get this error

> Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xAD\xD8\xB1\xD9\x81' for column 'arabic' at row 1

every time I try  to input something  in Arabic, I googled a bit and found that setting charset into utf8_bin is solution, so I tried that and yet still getting same error, and the data is stored as "**?????**"

### Example

```
UPDATE `ci`.`patients` SET `Name` = 'حرف' WHERE `patients`.`ID` =3;
```

Result

??? is stored into DB

Comment: What _exactly_ did you try to switch the charset to utf8?

Comment: @arkascha i tried to switch table collation into utf8_bin

Comment: And your client runs in which encoding? And the input is in which encoding?

Answer (score 4):

Arabic text in mysql database using php correctly, make sure that:

1- MySQL charset:`UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)`

2- MySQL connection collation: `utf8_general_ci`

3- your database and table collations are set to: `utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci`

Then, add this code in your php script when you connect to db:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Comment: how can i construct my tables that all fields can accept arabic ?

Answer (score 1):

Set MySQL table charset to utf8, collation to utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci.

I'm not into php stuff but if you have some kind of connection string you should also set charset to utf8 within that string.